# Does Boost provide a template implementation of the wedge product?

Tags: linear-algebra, libraries

Does the boost C++ library implement the computation of the wedge product?

The wedge product [is mentioned here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/boost/geometry/arithmetic/cross_product.hpp), but it is not very clear (to me at least) whether there is a template implementation of it available.

Comment: What do you want the template type to be? The scalar that is used to express the individual components?

Comment: Yes, probably the space dimension, and the rank of respective tensors as well.